# Is there a format for Python that isn't just a long series of code blocks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm using the Jupyter notebook and was just wondering if there was any other way I can use Python that isn't just a long series of code blocks. Ideally, I'd like tabs or different files or just a slightly more adaptable organization system.

Comment: You can separate functions into different files and import them as needed, if that's what you're talking about

Comment: Oh awesome! How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Create a new file with a `.py` extension and make sure it's in the same directory as your current file then you can import it like any other module. So for example `myfile.py` can be used by doing `import myfile` as long as they are in the same directory.

Comment: [More info here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_modules.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In regards to specifically the following text in the OP's post:

> "any other way I can use Python that isn't just a long series of code blocks. Ideally, I'd like tabs or different files or just a slightly more adaptable organization system."

This new project **[codepod.io](https://codepod.io/)** looks like a really different way to address the OP's question about a more adaptable organization system:

> "Canvas-based Scalable Interactive Coding. CodePod.io is an open-source canvas-based coding IDE that helps programmers develop large, production-ready projects faster by presenting interactive coding (e.g., Jupyter) on a hierarchical, scoped, 2D canvas."

Post [here](https://twitter.com/stevejpurves/status/1656287722279956488) described it as, "opensource whiteboard based development for jupyter notebooks."

Before that, I would have referenced **[nbdev](https://nbdev.fast.ai/)** for questions in this area of developing projects with Jupyter notebooks as the basis. Or [ploomber](https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber): "Do you have legacy notebooks? Refactor them into modular pipelines with a single command."